# How to use the results of a reactive expression in an output

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a Shiny App that monitors my running containers on a host machine, and here is what I have tried so far. Question is how can I display the outputs, in this case (docker ps -a) contents in the mainPanel? I'm new to Rshiny, so any help will be much appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(ssh)    

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Dashboard"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("bttn", "Click")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        h1("Running containers"),
        textOutput("dispContainers")
      )
    )
  )

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
    session <- ssh_connect("jeroen@dev.opencpu.or")
      observeEvent(input$bttn, {
      ssh_exec_wait(session, command = 'docker ps -a')
    
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the other `ssh_exec_internal` instead to collect the output of your docker command. Something like:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session <- ssh_connect("jeroen@dev.opencpu.or")
  text_output <- reactiveVal("")
  observeEvent(input$bttn, {
    response <- ssh_exec_internal(session, command = 'docker ps -a')
    text_output(rawToChar(response$stdout))
  })
  output$dispContainers <- renderText(text_output())
}
```

You might also want to switch `textOutput` to `verbatimTextOutput` to get the text as you'd see it in a terminal.